# C++ std::vector::emplace_back doesn't compile with string-value class

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

```
/* Item.h */
struct Item {
    std::string name;

    Item(std::string _name) : name( std::move(_name) ) { }
};

/* main.cpp */
/* ... */
const int amount_of_items = val.size();
std::vector<Item> items(amount_of_items);

for( Json::Value::const_iterator itr = val.begin() ; itr != val.end() ; ++itr ) {
    items.emplace_back( "item_name" );
}
```

Results in:

```
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Item::Item()’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ In file included from main.cpp:8: Item.h:8:2: note: candidate: ‘Item::Item(std::__cxx11::string)’   Item(std::string _name) : name( std::move(_name) ) { }   ^~~~ Item.h:8:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I don't know why this wouldn't work - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you need a default constructor of `Item` for this sequence of code. The default constructor is disabled because you have a custom constructor for `Item`.

You can enable it by adding `Item()=default;`.

Besides that, you have a logical bug: `std::vector<Item> items(amount_of_items);` initiates `items` to  `amount_of_items` of default constructible elements. It isn't what you want according to the next sequence as by the end you'll have double the number of elements.

You should've written

```
std::vector<Item> items;
items.reserve(amount_of_items);
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
std::vector<Item> items(amount_of_items);
```

requires a default constructor for `Item`, since you have asked the compiler to populate the array with `amount_of_items` default-constructed `Item`s.

Instead, you need to write simply:

```
std::vector<Item> items;
```

since `emplace_back` will grow the array as necessary.

Note that you *can* call `items.reserve` if you want to reserve space for your `Item`s up front.

Answer (score 1):

You have not got a default constructor in your struct because you have added a non-default constructor. You could add back your default constructor.

But the line of error is actually your initialisation (amount of items) this is trying to default construct the the `item`s with the default c'tor.

So I recommend you add a default c'tor:

```
    Item() = default;
```

Or init with a string:

```
std::vector<Item> items(num_items, std::string(""));
```

Also your 'move' constructor should use r-value ref `&&` (and probably also explicit since it has ony one parameter):

```
    Item() = default;

    //             here
    //               V
    explicit Item(std::string &&_name) : name( std::move(_name) ) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling the `std::vector` constructor:

```
std::vector<Item> items(amount_of_items);
```

The default constructor of the contained type: `Item` is invoked. You should either define a default constructor:

```
Item() = default
```

Or use one of the other `std::vector` constructors that do not have this requirement:

```
std::vector<Item> items(amount_of_items, {""});
```